# How can I replace the conda package for libprotobuf with the cloned GitHub version within a conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, protobuf-c

I am trying to install `caffe` within a `conda` environment. `Caffe` needs Google's `protobuf` package. I had already `git clone`'d `protobuf` and have it within my `\usr` directories. However, when I try to install caffe within the conda environment, the version of `libprotobuf` installed doesn't correctly convert the `proto` file to `c++` code.

Consider the following code:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package test1;


message Datum {
  optional int32 channels = 1;
}
```

When I attempt to translate it from within my `base` environment, everything is fine:

```
(base) me@balin:~/Projects/caffe$ make clean
(base) me@balin:~/Projects/caffe$ make superclean
Deleting the following generated files:
./temp5.pb.cc
./temp5.pb.h
(base) me@balin:~/Projects/caffe$ protoc --cpp_out=. temp5.proto
(base) me@balin:~/Projects/caffe$ g++ temp5.pb.cc -c
(base) me@balin:~/Projects/caffe$
```

However, when I try the same thing in the environment I want to use for `caffe`, I get this result:

```
(dnn_track5) me@balin:~/Projects/caffe$ make clean
(dnn_track5) me@balin:~/Projects/caffe$ make superclean
Deleting the following generated files:
./temp5.pb.cc
(dnn_track5) me@balin:~/Projects/caffe$ protoc --cpp_out=. temp5.proto
(dnn_track5) me@balin:~/Projects/caffe$ g++ temp5.pb.cc -c
temp5.pb.cc: In member function ‘virtual const char* test1::Datum::_InternalParse(const char*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)’:
temp5.pb.cc:150:58: error: ‘ReadVarint’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
           channels_ = ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ReadVarint(&ptr);
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
temp5.pb.cc:150:58: note: suggested alternative: ‘ReadVarint32’
           channels_ = ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ReadVarint(&ptr);
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                          ReadVarint32
```

All I can think to do is replace each file within the `~\anaconda2\envs\dnn_track5` sub-directories that were installed by `conda` with the files installed when I built `protobuf` from the `GitHub` clone. Am I right in this (I doubt it).

How can I create a conda environment where I can use `caffe` and still have a working `protobuf`?

Comment: How old is your clone from github and which version did `conda` install. I would not suggest to mess with the files conda has installed manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to use conda to install directly from a github repo, so it is worth to look at why your code is not working in your `caffe` env.

As of [this commit](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/commit/91ed6dcb5b3b44dbca3f468444f74b4b048bab23)(From October 2019) there is a distinction between

```
::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ReadVarint64
```

and

```
::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ReadVarint32
```

When you `conda install caffe`, it downloads(at least for me) `libprotobuf-3.11.2`, which is the most recent version from December 2019, so the version downloaded as a dependency for `caffe` is actually more recent than what you are trying to use in your code.

You have several options now:

1. Request a specific version of protobuf that has the API you want to use. I.e. 3.10.0, which is from 3rd October 2019:

   `conda create -n caffe -c conda-forge python=3.7 caffe libprotobuf=3.10.0`
2. Create a custom conda channel and put your own `libprotobuf.tar.bz2` in there
3. Adjust your code to use the most recent `libprotobuf` API